# Node js do something every 2 minutes, until a json which is checked every few seconds changes

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

To change a procedure while my programm is running, i want to manually change a value in a .json object from 0 to 1.
Now I want my programm to:

1. check the .json every few seconds (or even without timer, as often as possible) for changes.
2. refresh a browser page (using puppeteer) every 2 minutes, until the .json changes.
   How do i combine these 2 steps?

Im thinking about something like this:

```js
function checkJson() {
    var jsonArray = require('./sole.json');
    var startOrStop = jsonArray.startstop;
    return startOrStop;
    }
    
    function run(){
        while (checkJson() == 0) {
          //every 2min  ->>> await page.reload();
        }
    }
```

Is this even possible? Thanks in advance. If I explained it too indistinct, please let me know.

Comment: Do you know about `window.setTimeout()`? That might solve your problem (link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp)

Comment: Hey, yes i know about this, but i couldnt figure out at the time beeing, how to implement it, to make it work how i want it. As its name says, its a timeout, so when i call it (for like the 2minutes pause), it doesnt check the .json for a value change for 2minutes...

Comment: `setTimeout` is here a bad choice. Use `fs.watchFile` from the node `fs` module. It was build for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with the `fs.watchFile` method.

```js
const fs = require("fs");

// watch for file changes
// https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_fs_watchfile_filename_options_listener
fs.watchFile("./config.json", {
    interval: 1000 // set custom polling interval
}, (cur, prev) => {


    // prev & cur are file "Stats":
    // see more here https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/fs.html#fs_class_fs_stats
    console.log("File changed", cur, prev)


    // read file contents after changes
    // "require" here does not work, du to caching
    fs.readFile("./config.json", (err, data) => {

        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            process.exit();
        }

        // convert the plain text to a js object
        let json = JSON.parse(data);

        console.log(json);

    });


});
```

First, watch for file changes (with a custom pollin interval if needed), then read the content from the file.

`require(...)` here would not work, because it caches its required modules. So read the content of the file with `fs.readFile`, parse it with `JSON.parse` to get a valid js object and perform your check/stuff on it.

Simple, pretty straight forward, without external dependencies.

If you need something else, or explain it more detailed, let me know.